# RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same, but I set model and data to cuda

Tags: pytorch

I set both my model and data to CUDA device.

However, the error says:

> RuntimeError: Input type (torch.cuda.FloatTensor) and weight type (torch.FloatTensor) should be the same

[image]

Comment: You likely have not transferred your data to the correct device properly. Can you show the line where you transferred your data, *as well as* the full error backtrace?

Comment: thanks for replying, I used x, y = x.cuda(), y.cuda() in every iteration from the dataloader. I have fixed the problem because the model I wrote that had several 'class', but I did not instantiate those classes in the __init__ part. When I instantiated them in the __init__, it went okay. But thanks!!!!